# Calling multiple variables in chef code

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I have the following set in my attributes file

```
default[:iptables][:ports] = [22,21]
default[:iptables][:ubnet] = ["192.168.0.0/24"]
```

I have the following in my template.erb file

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

<%- node[:iptables][:ports].each do |port| -%>

-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport <%= port %> -j ACCEPT

<%- end -%>

<% node[:iptables][:subnet].each do |subnet| -%>

-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -s <%= subnet %> -m tcp -p tcp --dport <%= port %> -j ACCEPT

<%- end -%>
```

I want to end up with something like this when i run the code

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -s 192.168.0.0/16 -m tcp -p tcp --dport  25 -j ACCEPT
```

Unfortunately when i run the code as is, i get the following error

```
Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError (undefined local variable or method 'port' for #<Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateContext:0x00000006e7cd80>)
```

The first half of the code works as expected but the second block is the one giving me issues. I also do not want to hard code port 25. Can someone help me rewrite this?

Comment: Show your `template` resource declaration in your recipe!

Answer (score 1):

In the subnet line you put `--dport <%= port %>` but don't indicate where the `25` is supposed to come from.

All data has to come from somewhere, either put it in the template directly, or in node attribute data and then reference it in the template.